# Execute php script only when offline

Tags: php, offline

I have a php login script thats executed from the top of my html file.  Is there a way to NOT execute this php code when using it offline?

The goal is:
I have a webapp that can be cached on the mobile phone.
When the user has no network it should still be possible to open and use the app.
But when offline it can't connect to the user database for authentication.

So:

- When online: Execute the login script
- When offline: "skip" the loginscript

I was thinking something like this:

```
<?php

function getStatus($ip,$port){
   $socket = @fsockopen($ip, $port, $errorNo, $errorStr, 3);
   if(!$socket) return "offline";
     else return "online";
}

echo getStatus("sitename.com", "80");
?>
```

But then instead of "echo online" it should execute the php script, when offline "do nothing"
But you cant "echo" php code within php code.

Any ideas on how to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP works on server side so It will not be able to login when user is offline.
The caching is done only of output files such as

> html,js,css,images

etc but `Cookies` can not be edited*(actully they can be by javascript)* without connecting to server.

Comment: The idea is to not use the login script at all when being offline...So there will be NO authentication when offline (site is cached only after user is logged in and online)

Comment: If the user is offline in no way it can connect to server and login.

Comment: That is why i don't want the authentication script being loaded when user is offline...Then is just shows all the content.

Case online: Userauthentication is loaded,   
Case offline: Userauthentication is NOT used at all and all content is visable

Comment: if it cant contact to server as it is offline it cant even run the script for shure. if you have any JavaScript for login then the case is diff

Answer (score 4):

PHP is executed on the server side, not the client side. If a website is cached, you might not even contact the webserver at all.

In fact, making the server execute the PHP code while offline is impossible, since you won't be in contact with the server at all!

Comment: Ans when the script is also cached?

Comment: @bafplus The PHP script won't be cached, because it's never sent to the client. What _is_ sent to the client is what the PHP script _returns_. This your browser can cache.

Comment: So what happends if the browser encounters an include: some.php file in the header when offline? Does it just skip and process the page as normal? (if yes then i'm already saved ;-) )

Comment: The browser doesn't encounter an `include()`, ever. Again, this happens on the server side. Open your browser, navigate to the site, click "View Page Source". _This_ is what the browser gets. It doesn't get the PHP code behind it at all, only what the PHP prints out.

Comment: So when cached, there is no include so the webpage is rendered as "normal" (without login)?